# How do I get the filename programmatically to use with this code?

Tags: xpages, xpages-ssjs

The code below is the computed image source for an image control on my custom control.  If I run it just like it stands it puts in photo.jpg and works fine.  The problem is I want to pass that value programmatically.  I have an upload control (fileUpload1) and a download control (fileDownload1) on the custom control as well.  I've tried document1.photo which is where the jpg file is stored.  I've tried several variations of currentdocument.getitemvalue, getitem, getattachments.  But, so far, I have found no way to do this. In addition, I have tried setting the value of filename to the value of the upload control and the download control with no success.

I know this is probably simple, but, as a client developer, it's not simple to me.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

```
var doc:NotesDocument = currentDocument.getDocument ();
var UID:string = doc.getUniversalID().toString();
var fp:string = database.getFilePath();
var filename = "photo.jpg"

return '/0/' + UID + '/$file/' + filename
```

Thanks, 
MJ

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There may be other ways to achieve this but here's what I usually do:

with image controls I need to be aware that computed resource URLs are in most cases prepended with the database's relative path ending with the database filename. So all I have to add is the usual file attachment URL as in

```
/0/docUnid/$File/imageFileName
```

If there is a chance that you have more than one file attached to your doc I need to find out which one of them is the one I wish to display. This can be done by looping through

```
currentDocument.getAttachmentList(fieldName)
```

which delivers a `java.util.List` of `NotesEmbeddedObject` elements. Using methods like `.getName()` I then can find the one file you're looking for.

**EDIT:**
quick example using a repeat to display multiple images sattached to a single richtext field (there may be better solutions esp. regarding the way to filter unwanted file types; I'm using file extensions, only allowing .jpg, .png and .gif). Images are displayed as simple html  list elements:

```
<ul>
    <xp:repeat id="repeat1" rows="30" var="pic">
        <xp:this.value><![CDATA[#{javascript:
    var att:java.util.List=docCar.getAttachmentList("Body");
    var it=att.listIterator();
    //new empty array, to be used as the repeater's datasource
    var arr=[]; 
    //build base path for each image file
    var unid=docCar.getDocument().getUniversalID();
    var p="/0/" + unid + "/$File/";
    while(it.hasNext()){
        var e:NotesEmbeddedObject=it.next();
        if(e.getName().endsWithIgnoreCase(".png") || 
            e.getName().endsWithIgnoreCase(".jpg") || 
            e.getName().endsWithIgnoreCase(".gif")){
            //push complete filepath + image filename to array
            arr.push(p + e.getName());
        }
    }
    return arr;}]]></xp:this.value>
        <li>
            <xp:image url="#{javascript:pic}" id="image1">
            </xp:image>
        </li>
    </xp:repeat>
</ul>
```

Hope this helps

Comment: So, how do I compute the value of imagefilename?

Comment: as I explained above: by calling currentDocument.getAttachmentList(fieldName) (retirieving a list of embeddedObjects from a specified field) Or you use the method you mentioned yourself using the JS version of @AttachmentNames (retrieving a list of file names stored anywhere inside your doc)

Answer (score 0):

Well, I think I have it figured out.  Here is the code that now works:

> var doc:NotesDocument = currentDocument.getDocument ();
>   var UID:string = doc.getUniversalID().toString(); var fp:string =
>   database.getFilePath();
>
> var filename = @AttachmentNames()
>
> return '/0/' + UID + '/$file/' + filename

MJ

Comment: Yes this works as well. 
Hint: you need to take precautions if there is a chance your documents could be containing more than one attachments; @AttachmentNames is giving you a list of names no matter which RT field the files are stored in. Also you must handle cases where there aren't any attachments, or where you have attachment types other than images etc.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestions.  I need all the help I can get.  If you have some sample code of how you would handle multiple attachments and no attachments, I would be interested in looking at it.

Comment: 1.: multiple attachments aren't too difficult to handle; I'll try to come up with a simple example later this week
2.: handling different file types isn't so easy: as NotesEmbedded objects are agnostic to file types you'll have to check file extensions, I'm afraid. I may be wrong, though, maybe someone has a proper idea to handle this. Otherwise you could rule out anything that comes with an extension other than .png, .jpg or .gif. Not really perfect, I admit. But other than that you may have to look for Java classes to analyze the files themselves

Comment: I think the file extensions would work for what I'm doing.